# Scipy optimizations methods select nan for input parameter

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I've a mathematical function by 4 parameters input. Also there are bounds in parameters:

```
a = [0,2]
b = [-1,1]
c = [eps, inf]
d = [-inf, inf]
```

I want to minimize the final value and find best parameter in function.
In Scipy there are just 3 functions to support bounding optimization problems as `'TNC', 'SLSQP' and 'L-BFGS-B'`  [refrence: [optimizations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)].

The problem is when `SLSQP` and sometimes other methods select `nan` for parameters and thus, result of function goes to `nan` for value. It's happend suddenly, for e.g. in `step i-1` run normal and return real value, but for `step i` input parameters is `nan` and so final results goes to `nan`. From then on, inputes and outputs is `nan` while maximum iterations is reached!

Where is the issue?

The summery code is here:

```
bnds = [(eps, 2.), (-1.,1.), (eps, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf)]
scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp(myFunc, params, bounds=bnds)
```

or

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(myFunc, params, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds)
```

---

**Because of there are no real solution for this issue, I was forced to change my problem!**

Comment: I imagine that this can happen under certain circumstances. Without knowing the function you wish to optimize, it is probably impossible to find out what is happening.

Comment: The function is very complex and very long. It's a probability density function for a non-closed from distribution. But this function work correctly.

Comment: You wish to minimize a PDF on an unbounded domain? Anyway, are you certain that the function works well for very large parameters (many kernel density estimates might not for example).