# Scipy selects nan as inputs while minimizing

Tags: scipy, nan, nonlinear-optimization, minimization

I have this objective function (in python) :

```
actions= [...] # some array
Na= len(actions)    
# maximize p0 * qr(s,a0,b0) + ... + pn * qr(s,an,bn)
def objective(x):
        p = x[:Na] # p is a probability distribution
        b = x[Na:2 * Na] # b is an array of positive unbounded scalars
        q = np.array([qr(s, actions[a], b[a]) for a in range(0, Na)]) # s is an array
        rez = - np.dot(p, q) # np stands for numpy library
        return rez
```

`qr` and `qc` are regression trees, these are functions mapping arrays to scalars.

I have these constraints :

```
# p0 * qc(s,a0,b0) + ... + pn * qc(s,an,bn) < beta
def constraint(x):
    p = x[:Na]
    b = x[Na:2 * Na]
    q = np.array([qc(s, actions[a], b[a]) for a in range(0, Na)])
    rez = beta - np.dot(p, q) # beta is a scalar        
    return rez

# elements of p should sum to 1
def constraint_proba_sum_1(x):
    p = x[:Na]
    rez = 0
    for i in range(0, Na):
        rez += p[i]
    rez = 1 - rez
    return rez
```

How I minimize :

```
constraints = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint},
                   {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_proba_sum_1})

res = opt.minimize(fun=objective, x0=np.array([0.5, 0.5, 10, 10]), constraints=constraints,
                       bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, None), (0, None)])
```

The problem is `opt.minimize` uses `nan` arrays as inputs sometimes during its minimization process "slsqp". Thus the `qr` tree raises errors.Why would it evaluate such arrays, in what circumstances ?

I do realize this issue is the same as this post [Scipy optimizations methods select nan for input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963248/scipy-optimizations-methods-select-nan-for-input-parameter) but it is not resolved and it looks like function dependent.

**EDIT** : It appears that if I remove the constraint constraint_proba_sum_1(x), I dont have NaN value as input anymore.

**EDIT 2** : I tryed another API, pyOPT with SLSQP optimization and I have the same issue.

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?   It helps to have something that we can copy and run ourselves.  Maybe you can create simplified versions of `actions`, `qc`, `qr` (and anything else undefined here) to create a runnable example.

Comment: Well I tried, https://pastebin.com/uEVamXXU, but it don't raise any error. I think the shape of qr and qc functions are the main problem and unfortunatly, I can't create a example of them without giving the whole code.  It uses heavy frameworks like supervised learning and reinforcement learning. Maybe it's more a math related issue.

Comment: It appears that if I remove the constraint constraint_proba_sum_1(x), I dont have NaN value as input anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I observed a similar behavoir for scipy's `differential_evolution` optimizer, and I could trace this back to the `polish` argument, which runs a local minimization after the global optimization. Since this appeared only after the max iterations of the DE optimizer (apparently the parameters of my model cannot be identified from the data I have at hand), the init of the local minimizer from the DE opt object caused similiar effects as the other posts describe.

My fix was to catch within the objective function for occurence of NaN values and raising an exception, since this happens for my only when the DE optimizer could not find an optimium.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer to this question, but I have experienced the same behaviour as you in my own optimization script and wanted to share my way of fixing it.

First of all, also in my case it helped to remove one of the constraints. The reason that this helps is because `Scipy.minimize` cannot handle an optimization where you start with voilated constraints. So if `c == 0.0` and `c = 0.3` at the start point, then it will, at some point, set `nan` values for the design variables when it's optimizing. Of course, just removing a constraint is generally not an option, so what helped in my case was to set stricter bounds on the design variables such that it is less likely to start with a point that is invalid (hence, has constraint violations). Note that this assumes that you run the optimization multiple times at different start points (which is true for my set-up). In your case, I think it is just a matter of choosing a start point `x0` which has an unviolated (valid) `constraint_proba_sum_1(x)`.

So in conclusion, one way of avoiding this issue is to make sure that the start point of your optimization is a valid point in terms of the constraints that you have provided.